# Add class when div is in the viewport (scroll horizontal)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a horizontal scrollable div with different element inside; is that possibile to check when the user arrive to determinate element, and add a class to this element? I don't found any solution.

Thank you!

Comment: Please add some code so we can see more clearly what you want to do. It may be that IntersectionObserver would be helpful but difficult to know what to advise without seeing a (minimal) example of your structure.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```js
$('.flex').scroll(function() {
  var currentleft = $('.flex').scrollLeft();

  $(".flex span").each(function(index, i) {
    let beginningOfElem = $(this).offsetLeft;
    let endOfElem = beginningOfElem + $(this).outerWidth();


    if (currentleft < $(this).offsetLeft) {
      $(this).removeClass('redbg').addClass('nobg');
    } else {
      $(this).removeClass('nobg').addClass('redbg');
    }

    if ($(this).position().left <= 0 || $(this).position().left > $('.flex').width()) {
      $(this).removeClass('redbg').addClass('nobg');
    }



  });
});
```

```css
.flex{
  width: 200px;
  display: flex;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.flex > span{
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  padding: 1rem 3rem;
}

.redbg{
  background: red;
}

.nobg{
  background: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flex">
  <span class="redbg">1</span>
  <span>2</span>
  <span>3</span>
  <span>4</span>
  <span>5</span>
  <span>6</span>
  <span>7</span>
  <span>8</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
$(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        $(".content:last-child").toggleClass("active");
    });
});
```

Check out the codepen: https://codepen.io/jvkrakowski/pen/wvdywve

I would use flexbox instead of what I did in the codepen, though. `addClass` would work too. Check out the jquery docs: https://api.jquery.com/

Comment: This will only target the last element not the ones in the middle. Also, the class will keep flickering if you toggle it on scroll.